# How to use luxon in vue3

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, luxon

I want to use luxon in my vue 3 application (https://moment.github.io/luxon/#/)

But unfortunately it is not supporting vue3 right now. Thats why I want to wrap my application with luxon but I dont know how to do it exactly.

So in my component I imported luxon like this:

```
import { DateTime } from 'luxon';

methods: {
     getCurrentMonth() {
       const currentMonth = DateTime().month() + 1;
       return currentMonth;
}
}
```

But I am getting an error like this: Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Class constructor DateTime cannot be invoked without 'new'

I think that because I am using/wrapping luxon wrong in my vue3 application.

How can I fix it?

Comment: No support for a library is needed from the framework in such case. That you use Vue is irrelevant. The error means what it says, you called a constructor without `new` keyword. Consider referring to Luxon docs for the correct usage

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use `DateTime()` without `new` keyword (and config parameter, see [docs](https://moment.github.io/luxon/api-docs/index.html#datetime)).

I suggest to use [`DateTime.now()`](https://moment.github.io/luxon/api-docs/index.html#datetimenow) to get the current date and time. Moreover, [`month`](https://moment.github.io/luxon/api-docs/index.html#datetimemonth) is a member of `DateTime` object not a method.

Your code could be like the following:

```
import { DateTime } from 'luxon';

methods: {
    getCurrentMonth() {
        const currentMonth = DateTime.now().month + 1;
        return currentMonth;
    }
}
```

Comment: "There is no DateTime() constructor in luxon" - it's right in the doc you linked, `new DateTime(config: any)`

Comment: @EstusFlask you're right, I've corrected the answer, I did not take into account `new DateTime(config: any)` since I've never seen it in use